# OneToMany relation working on Prisma Database, but not on server

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql

In the mutation to create posts, I am using this code:

```
async function savePost(parent, args, context, info){

  let data = {...args}
  delete data.categories
  delete data.status

  if (!context.request.userId) {
    throw new Error('Please SignIn to continue.')
  }

  const post = await context.prisma.createPost({
    author: {
      connect: { id: context.request.userId }
    },
    categories: {
      set: args.categories,
    },
    status: args.status,
    ...data
  })

  return post

}
```

This connects the post to the author in the database. I got to know this by using Database Playground.

However, when I console.log the postToUpdate, it returns `author: null!
When I use gql on the client side, the same thing happens. The post does not have an author!

Though the author got saved in the database, I don’t see him/her on client and server side.

For reference, this is the Datamodel

```
enum Previledge {
  SUPERADMIN
  ADMIN
  MODERATOR
  AUTHOR
  READER
}

enum Category {
  TECH
  FIN
  DIGIMARK
  CODING
  TUTORIAL
  HOWTO
  WRITING
  INSPIRE
  SCIENCE
  POLITICS
  LIFESTYLE
  FOOD
  BUSINESS
  ENTREPRENEUR
  HISTORY
  HEALTH
  PET
  PARENTHOOD
  TRAVEL
  INDIA
  CHINA
  US
  UK
  WORLD
  NEWS
  REVIEW
}

enum PostStatus {
  PUBLISHED
  DRAFT
  DELETED
}

type Post {
  id: ID! @unique
  title: String!
  editorSerializedOutput: Json!
  editorCurrentContent: Json!
  editorHtml: String!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  author: User! @relation(name: "PostsAndUser")
  categories: [Category]!
  thumbnail: Json!
  status: PostStatus!
}

type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  socialId: String! @unique
  fname: String!
  lname: String!
  name: String!
  phone: String @unique
  email: String! @unique
  gender: String
  birthday: String
  bio: String
  posts: [Post]! @relation(name: "PostsAndUser")
  profilePicture: String!
  followers: [User]!
  previledge: [Previledge]!
  signUpMethod: String!
  accessToken: String!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  createdAt: DateTime!
}
```

This is the entire schema:

```
# import * from './generated/prisma.graphql'

scalar DateTime

type Message {
  code: Int
  message: String
}

type Mutation {
  signIn(
    socialId: String!
    fname: String!
    lname: String!
    name: String!
    phone: String
    email: String!
    gender: String
    birthday: String
    bio: String
    profilePicture: String!
    signUpMethod: String!
    accessToken: String!
  ): User!
  signOut: Message
  savePost(
    title: String!
    editorSerializedOutput: Json!
    editorCurrentContent: Json!
    editorHtml: String!
    categories: [Category]!
    thumbnail: Json!
    status: PostStatus!
  ): Post!
}

type Query {
  users: [User]!
  me: User
  canUpdatePost(id: ID!): Post
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  fname: String!
  lname: String!
  name: String!
  phone: String
  email: String!
  gender: String
  birthday: String
  bio: String
  posts(where: PostWhereInput, orderBy: PostOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): [Post!]
  profilePicture: String!
  followers(where: UserWhereInput, orderBy: UserOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): [User!]
  previledge: [Previledge]!
  signUpMethod: String!
  updatedAt: String!
  createdAt: String!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `info` as second parameter to `createPost` function of Prisma binding.

There are chances that `author` field is being queried from client in response of `savePost` mutation but since there is no second parameter passed to `createPost`, prisma is returning only scalar fields. Since `author` field is defined as required in `Post` type, GraphQL validation will fail in case `author` is queried from client but not returned by resolver.

Change this:

```
const post = await context.prisma.createPost({
    author: {
      connect: { id: context.request.userId }
    },
    categories: {
      set: args.categories,
    },
    status: args.status,
    ...data
  })
```

to:

```
const post = await context.prisma.createPost({
    author: {
      connect: { id: context.request.userId }
    },
    categories: {
      set: args.categories,
    },
    status: args.status,
    ...data
  }, info)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you don't specify the second argument of `createPost`, it will only return scalar fields.
Try:

```js
  const post = await context.prisma.createPost({
    author: {
      connect: { id: context.request.userId }
    },
    categories: {
      set: args.categories,
    },
    status: args.status,
    ...data
  }, `{
   author {
     id
   }
  }`)

  console.log(post)
```

Also, type `Post` seems to be absent from your schema, you might need to generate it again.

Comment: Type post is in generated prisma.graphql

Comment: Everytime I create Post, it is creating the Post, but giving an error:
`Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.author.`